# Hibernate/JPA - configure different entity schemas/catalogs from configuration

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a couple of entities living in the same MySQL instance but under different databases (catalogs). Now usually what I did, when defining my entities, is I have used the @Table annotation to set the catalog for my entities:

```
@Table(name="customer" , catalog="cat1")
@Table(name="vip_customer" , catalog="cat2")
```

This worked ok until I need to define the catalogs via configuration. Is there a way to do that (to do basically the same thing programmatically that Hibernate probably does when parsing these annotations)?

Comment: Did you try `hibernate.default_catalog` property?

Comment: How would that help? I have 2 distinct catalogs.

Comment: This is just the only one property somehow related to the topic. I am afraid there is no way to config table to catalog mapping in hibernate configuration file.

Comment: Yes exactly, that's why I was looking for a programmatic solution eg. the same way Hibernate handles the annotations

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box way to do this. What you can do, is to create a custom `MetadataContributor` and replace the catalog names in `Table` of the various `PersistentClass`.